# Trying to sum up nested lists but receive error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Tags: python-3.x, sum, int, nested-lists

Im using python 3 to create a list of random dice rolls and add them up, however when i try to add all the totals it gives me TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list. What to do?

```
count = 0
lista=[[] for q in range(5)]
while count<len(lista):
    import random
    c=random.randrange(1,7,1)
    lista[count].append(c)
    count += 1

print(lista)
total=sum(lista)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi You are trying to add int value to list So, Type mismatch error,
You have to try to add int value with list value

```
count = 0
total = 0
lista=[[]for q in range(5)]
while count<len(lista):
    import random
    c=random.randrange(1,7,1)
    lista[count].append(c)
    total += lista[count][0]
    count += 1
print(lista)
print total
```

Answer (score 0):

No offence, but oh my god, that is so unpythonistic that my eyes bleed. But obviously you have to start somewhere ;)
I guess you have done C development previously. In Python you don't need to preallocate memory or arrays. You also can iterate over any iterable directly, no need to use an increasing integer index.

Just do:

```
import random
lista = [random.randrange(1, 7, 1) for q in range(5)]
print(lista)
total = sum(lista)
```

This will create `lista` as a list of five integers returned by `random.randrange()`.

Your problem is: when you do `lista=[[] for q in range(5)]`, you get a list of 5 empty lists (`[[], [], [], [], []]`). Then when you `lista[count].append(c)` you end up with a list of list containing an integer each (`[[5], [1], [3], [4], [3]]`). `sum` will then try to sum the inner lists, not the integers. That fails.